# Float:right + keeping it fixed

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website with a div on the right side 
    (float:right;).
But I want it to also behave like a fixed div.
but when adding 
    (position:fixed;)
the div doesn't behave like a floating div anymore..
so the left div takes all place and overlaps the right div.

hoping for an answer...

Answer (score 5):

```
#div-right {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0px;
   width: 100px;
}
#div-left {
   margin-right: 100px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4xEyE/3/)

Comment: Thx, but it is a template for several pages, not all pages have the right div, in that case the left div must take all width...

Comment: So make two classes, or two css files. One for pages with right div, one for pages without right div. You can even put style to HTML.